# ReactJS + Formsy Mixin implementation issue

Tags: reactjs, mixins

This is what I have been trying to do:

Sidebar of a page has a couple of links say Step 1, Step 2 etc. The last tab in the sidebar has the Submit button which generates the POST call to my service.

In the parent page called CreateItem.js, I have the sidebar with:

```
<Sidebar width="15rem" open={true}>
<div>
    <div className="panel">
        <a href="#basic-info">Step 1: Basic Info</a>
    </div>
    <div className="panel">
        <a href="#content">Step 2: Content</a>
    </div>
</div>
</Sidebar>
<Mainbar>
<div>
    <section className="basic-info" id="basic-info">
        <BasicInfoPage user={this.props.user} itemId={this.props.params.id} />
    </section>
    <section className="content" id="content">
        <ContentPage user={this.props.user} />
    </section>
</div>
</Mainbar>
```

and each tab has it's own formsy form and render function. Basically all the sections are put into one page but just rendered section by section.

My Questions:
 1. How does the submit button in the last section say contentpage gather all the data from all the previous sections above it? I realize there is a formsy onSumbit function but the forms are in each of the sections so I don't understand How I can encapsulate all the data into a  single json.

Any help/ tip is greatly appreciated! More than willing to give more info!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you should use [Flux](https://github.com/facebook/flux) or [Reflux](https://github.com/spoike/refluxjs) architecture to collect all data of each section and store it in a store. In this way, you can easily get data you want.